# Paypal adaptive payments fee

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using paypal api to accept and send payments. When accepting payments i can get payment fee amount from IPN message, but i can't get it for payments, which are send using adaptive payments api. Also i tried to request adaptive payments transaction details, but it does not contain fee amount either.

I found this topic [Paypal Adaptive Payment IPN fees information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906912/paypal-adaptive-payment-ipn-fees-information) and tried to specify IPN url in sandbox, but i didn't get any additional info about payment. Actually i didn't get any IPN message to that url.

Is it possible to get fee for adaptive payments?